# Winsock TCP buffering behaviour

Tags: windows, winsock

Firstly, the environment of this issue;

Windows XP SP3
Exclusive use of overlapped I/O
Tx and Rx socket buffering disabled
TCP transport
Nagle disabled
I/O completion port
Wireshark used to analyze network traffic

What I'm observing with my application is a discrepancy between network traffic reception and my application's notification of these events.

To best illustrate this issue the following is a sample of a TCP stream of one such case:

```
#   RelTime  Dir  Len
1   0        Rx   ACK
2   10       Rx   536
3   9        Rx   536
4   0        Tx   ACK
5   10       Rx   536
6   10       Rx   536
7   0        Tx   ACK
8   9        Rx   536
9   9        Rx   429
```

(The posted buffers for receiving this data are 2044 bytes each)

The above 3109 bytes are received by my application in 3 notifications as 2044 bytes, 100 bytes, 965 bytes. Thus, the stack appears to have waited until it has sent two ACKs (#4, #7) before deciding to propagate the data to userland (and again on #9)

Now apart from appearing to contradict all the Winsock documentation regarding notification (of which states immediate notification, which in this case would be 536 bytes each) the delay in notification (e.g, ~40ms) is quite significant especially in my case which is a game server modelled on time-delay game input distribution.

What I'm after is an proper explaination regarding the semantics of the relationship between TCP on the wire and userland notification via Winsock.

Thanks,

Matt.

P.S., I've already questioned the MSDN Winsock kernel forum about this but to no avail.

P.P.S., It's 3am so I hope my question made atleast some sense.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess: Turn off the Windows Firewall or any other security product you have installed (and reboot).

Also, look for any other non-Microsoft LSPs that might be installed. I've seen some weird networking issues because someone installed some 3rd party proxy and networking utils.  http://www.herongyang.com/Windows/Winsock-netsh-winsock-show-catalog-LSP.html

Comment: My system is what one would describe as minimalistic; I have no security software nor firewalls and almost all services are disabled.

I have analyzed the pipeline from source to sink (ie., drivers, SPI LSPs, etc) and nothing unusual ellicted.

I've also tested this on an alternate machine incase it's a design choice with my network driver yet it renders the same results.

Comment: Does the problem go away on Windows 7 or Windows Server?  The only other idea I have it to experiment with SO_RCVBUF socket options and maybe SO_RCVLOWAT. But tweaking these settings might make it worse.